# Binding, Updating Listbox with List, Dictionary or DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox, idictionary

I have been looking into this for a while and there are lots of questions on this topic but I have not been able to find a clear answer.

I have a `Listbox` (listBox1) and `IDictionary` (clients) object in Windows Forms application.

```
public static IDictionary<string, Object> clients = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
```

I can use the following to populate the `ListBox` from the `IDictionary`:

```
 listBox1.DataSource=clients.ToList();
 form_m.listBox1.DisplayMember = "key";
```

**Question #1**:
What is the correct way to use `DataBinding` with a `ListBox`?
I have tried the following:

```
listBox1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", clients, "Key");
```

Getting this exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Property accessor 'Key' on object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Net.Sockets.Socket, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' threw the following exception:'Object does not match target type.'
>
> System.Reflection.TargetException:
>   Object does not match target type.

And when trying:

```
listBox1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", clients.ToList(), "Key");
```

I get this exception:

> System.ArgumentException:
>   Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.

**Question #2:**
This works fine but I want the ListBox to update when there is a new key/value added or removed from `IDictionary`. As I understand, I need to make and use extended `Observable` class of `IDictionary`. Or, is there another simpler solution for this?

PS: It does not necessarily have to be the `IDictionary`, any data structure would do. But, I need the ListBox to update, as changes are made in Data structure.

One such example I found was [can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/)

Answer (score 0):

For question #1, you can bind a `Dictionary` to a `ListBox` by creating a `BindingSource` from it:

```
listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(clients, null); 
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"; 
listBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

For question #2, you can use a `BindingList` as a `DataSource`, and the `ListBox` will update automatically as the `BindingList` changes.

For example, if you drop a `ListBox` and a `Button` on a form, this code will add 5 items to the `BindingList` and bind the `ListBox` to it in the `Load` event. Then in the `Button_Click` event, another item is added to our `BindingList` and the `ListBox` reflects the change immediately:

```
BindingList<int> items = new BindingList<int>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add some items to our binding list
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        items.Add(i);
    }

    // Bind our listbox
    listBox1.DataSource = items;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add an item to our binding list on each click
    items.Add(items.Count + 1);
}
```